# GQLGen related list query limit using entgql

Tags: go, gql, gqlgen, ent

I'm using entgql implementation of gqlgen (https://entgo.io/docs/graphql/) and have run into an issue where after my query reaches a certain size, it starts returning related lists as empty lists.

Rough data as follows

```
type Partner implements Node {
    id: ID!
    system: [System]
}
type System implements Node {
    id: ID!
    name: String
}
type PartnerConnection {
  totalCount: Int!
  pageInfo: PageInfo!
  edges: [PartnerEdge]
}

type PartnerEdge {
  node: Partner
  cursor: Cursor!
}
type Query {
  partners(
    first: Int
  ): PartnerConnection!
}
```

And my query is as follows

```
query {
  partners {
    edges {
      node {
        system {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've found that after the count of partner records goes over a certain count, the system list starts returning as an empty list for every record regardless of what data there is.

If I change my query to `partners(first:100)` then it returns the systems lists fine.

I get that I need to write my queries better so I'm not running into these limits in the first place, but I would like to know what exactly is causing this and how to possibly increase the limit in the short term.

The fact that it just starts returning empty lists rather than throwing some sort of limit error is also an issue.

I'm also unaware of the correct terminology around this issue which makes searching for a solution even more difficult.